# Percent change vs difference in logs: Which to prefer when forcasting non-stationary series with rare large excursions?

Tags: applied-econometrics, log-linearization, forecasting, numerical-methods

One of the most common ways to convert a non-stationary time series into a stationary one is to take the difference in logs. This is approximately equal to the percentage change for small changes, and has the advantage of being unitless, and also that the percentage increase and the percentage decrease is the same when using this approximation, which is often convenient.

Suppose I wish to do forecasting of a series. Suppose further that when I look at my data I see that the average absolute percentage change is quite small, less than half a percent, but that the maximum change is up around 10 or 12 percent.

In this setting, to minimize forecast error, should one still use the difference in log transformation? Or should one calculate the actual percentage change in the independent and dependent variables, and use that instead?

Comment: Hi: everyhing you said sounded right to me. I'm just not sure about your wanting to change all the regressors to percent change units also. That would help for interpretation ( a percentage change in x causes a whatever percent change in y ) but you may want to try not changing the RHS variables to percent changes. That will give different and maybe better results ? Hopefully, someone else can comment and expand on this issue.